# How to enable audio output via HDMI from HD 6850?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, audio, hdmi, digital-audio

I have an HD 6850 connected to 32" LCD TV via HDMI. The video is ok, but there's no sound. AMD HDMI OUTPUT is set as default but doesn't do anything. When I right-click and click on Test Windows shows me an error.

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3] [image: 4]

[Google Drive folder with screenshots](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B11ohRPKEs2SfkdHcldDSnB1amppOGNRbVFKdlVfNTd3V3Q0OEdUY2JaQlE1eGxEbjBRalE&authuser=0)

[image: catalyst]

Comment: Which version of AMD's Catalyst driver are you using?

Comment: 14.12 AMD Catalyst Omega Software

Comment: Can you please translate what is written in the Error box (3rd picture)? And have you checked for any option on your TV which enables or disables HDMI audio?

Comment: the translate is: "failed to reproduce the test tone". Yes, i explore all the tv menú :(.